# Issue with Python single and double underscore variables

Tags: python, inheritance

I am unsure what I am doing wrong; or why this is the case.

I've the following code:

```
class Expression (Node):
  """
  ...
  """

  def __init__ (self):
    self.__expressionType = None


  def expressionType (self):
    return self.__expressionType


class Number (Expression):
  """
  Number .
  """

  def __init__ (self, value):
    """
    Value is an entry of type Constant.
    """
    Expression.__init__(self)
    assert isinstance (value, KST.Constant)
    self.__constant = value
    self.__expressionType = value.elementType()
```

For a number object say `n = Number(KST.Constant(..))`, I am always returned None for the following statement—

```
 n.expressionType()
```

Now if I change the double underscores to single ones, it all works. I understand the difference between private and semi-private variables but why this is happening — I've no idea. Also, I've used "__" in a number of other places and it all seems to work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Comment: this would work if you defined `expressionType` on `Number` as well. but from code-duplication perspective, you would want to use a single underscore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Attribute names with double underscores are "[mangled](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)" to make it harder to have conflicting name in subclasses.

So use single underscores.

Comment: I got it. I understood the issue. What I now do is — `Expression.__init__(self, value.elementType())`. Do you think this is a better way of doing it? Obviously, I've added the `expressionType` to the constructor of `Expression`.

Comment: @flippex17_ Yes, call it `element_type()`. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ ;-)

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get that. My question was— 'should I use a single underscore or end up changing the way I call the constructor for the super class'? I am not concerned with variable naming as I use the Camel naming convention.

Comment: Yes, use single underscores. I think my answer was perfectly clear in that and very hard to misunderstand.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, "namemangling" occurs. In simple terms, Python will change the variable names so that the programmer can't access them by pure memory.

Example:

```
class A():
  var1 = 10    # typical variable
  __var2 = 20  # double-underscored variable
```

Now you'll notice that you can't access the double-underscored variable..

```
>>> A.var1
10
>>> A.__var2
  AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute '__var2'
```

..unless you know how Python changes your variable names

```
>>> a._A__var2
20
```

This is essentially getting the same behaviour as `private` in Java and other programming languages where you don't want programmers accidentally changing values.

Answer (score 0):

This is because [*name mangling*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) is happening.

- `expressionType` is defined in `Expression`.
- `n.__expressionType` will translate to `n._Expression__expressionType`.
- if you copy-paste the same `expressionType` method to the class `Number`, then because of method resolution order, it would go the the definition that appears in `Number` where `self.__expressionType` would mean `self._Number__expressionType`.

`n._Expression__expressionType` != `n._Number__expressionType`.

This would actually work:

```
class Expression(Node):
  def __init__(self):
    self.__expressionType = None
  def expressionType(self):
    return self.__expressionType

class Number(Expression):
  def __init__ (self, value):
    Expression.__init__(self)
    assert isinstance (value, KST.Constant)
    self.__constant = value
    self.__expressionType = value.elementType()
  def expressionType (self):
    return self.__expressionType
```

However, there is code duplication, so using a single underscore is better because it won't mangle the name of the attribute.